When do growth curves "reach maximum"?
I have been reading about growth curves, specifically those with upper and lower asymptotes, which have been asked about here before. See also Tjørve & Tjørve (2017).
In these models, is there a generally accepted value for when the outcome reaches the maximum value? Since it approaches an asymptote, it will never reach it, so have biologists established a value at which they can talk about it "reaching maximum"? E.g. at 95%, 99% of the upper asymptote?

In what context? in what application? Are you talking about partitioning growth phases in mathematical models, or growing a bucket of cells, checking the OD600, and saying "ok now it's ready"? Your citation describes work on mathematical growth models, but it does not seem to talk much about saturation. Most of the time we are not working in growing logistic curves into saturated systems (with some exceptions). Usually you harvest stuff mid-log-phase or you have a stably saturated system, so it's kind of a moot point.

@MaximilianPress I am not working on biological experiments, but rather learning about them for application in a different context and wanting to read about how biologists have treated this. I suppose my answer is closest to "saying 'ok now it's ready,'" but I don't know what an OD600 is, or what saturation is in this context.

OD600 is the standard experimental measurement of optical density of a microbial/cell culture, which is the main measurement that people use for growth in a laboratory context. Saturation of a culture is the same thing as your "maximum". But cultures at saturation are usually nasty to work with, so people generally use mid-log phase (which has standard OD600 values for different types of cells). However a stable natural ecosystem is usually "saturated" all the time (or cyclically varying around saturation). So it really does change depending on the context!
